# Issue with chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a project which runs perfectly on Firefox. How ever when i run it on chrome, for a few users, it says too many redirects?

Can anyone suggest possible reason/reasons as this peculiar scene occurs for a few users only and they are normal users like others.

Comment: You probably have a malfunctioning .htaccess statement or header redirect somewhere. Show your .htaccess if there is one

Comment: my .htaccess contains only this:   Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

Comment: what are your URLs? and where are urls being handled ? Please paste that code/URLs. so that we can try to tell something better.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers encode/decode urls/headers differently. And they keep requesting wrong URIs, thus getting eternally redirected. So "looking-safe-encoding-scheme" fails in Chrome.

Comment: So how am i supposed to handle this condition?

Comment: Boil down to the faulty URIs and see what you can change in your encoding scheme to fight the issue: you might even analyze USER_AGENT to serve different URIs to Chrome users. Or work out a universal code.